# Magento - Working with multiselect and Store view

Tags: magento, multi-select

I'm developing a new module for Magento and I need to use the Store View (like in CMS/pages or CMS/blocks).

Thanks to answer of Gergely Varga ([magento multiselect insert database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647921/magento-multiselect-insert-database/7651131#7651131)) I can now save the new item and automatically Magento saves the stores in the other table (I have 2, one for the item and one with the id of my item and the id of the store).

Now I have 3 problems or more:

- 1 - Grid.php doesn't show the stores that Magento saved in the stores table.
- 2 - If I try to modify an item, it doesn't load-show the stores that Magento saved when I created the item.
- 3 - I can't use the search with the Store view (I don't really care about this one).

Then, what is the problem? I followed the answer of Gergely Varga and I can't see anything different in the code of the CMS/page or CMS/block.

EDIT:

Do you want me to rewrite it or something? I really need help with this, is so frustrating...

The thing is that I am creating a module to add and manage banners. When I create a banner I need to asociate it to some parts of the web using the Store View multiselect. Now, thanks to that post ([magento multiselect insert database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647921/magento-multiselect-insert-database/7651131#7651131)), it's working, but when I am in the banners manage page, the store view column is not working (it doesn't shows anything). When I want to modify a banner, the same thing, it doesn't show the asociated Store Views.

Thanks, regards.

Comment: nice conversation you are having here dude:) but have you tried yo read your question before you posted it?

Comment: Hi, if you are laughing at me I can only say that English is not my first language and I'm trying to write correctly.

Comment: I'm not laughing at you but try to build a question in your main language first and then translate it to get the question right.

Comment: I think that what I have written makes sense, I'm sorry if it doesn't.

Do you need that I explain something more about my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's all working (the search is not working if you want to use the Store Views field, but I don't care about that).

I don't really know how have I fix all that, but it's working. I think that I had some problems in the models.